# R: Draw 100 random prices from each cut quality in diamonds data set?

Tags: r, dataframe, random, sample

I am using the diamonds data set:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")
```

and I have to make a data frame that randomly takes 100 prices from each cut quality (Fair, Good, Very Good, Premium, Ideal) which would give me 500 data points. I'm having some trouble getting there and any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's a formula I tried but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to include all of the subsets that fall under 'cut'.

```
diamonds$price[ sample( diamonds$cut, size=100, replace=FALSE )]
```

I also tried using the aggregate function but that seemed to bring me even further away from where I was supposed to go. I'm sure I'm just missing something fairly obvious but I'm very new to this and I can't find anything about it online. Thank you!

Thanks to Camille I was able to do it with:

```
 Test.1<-diamonds %>%
      group_by(cut) %>%
      sample_n(size = 100) %>%
      count(price)
```

I just can't seem to work with the data now because I need to find the mean standard deviation etc. for each cut quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using split-apply-combine logic.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)

head(diamonds)

xy <- split(diamonds, f = diamonds$cut)

xy <- lapply(xy, FUN = function(x) {
  x[sample(1:nrow(x), 100), ]
})

xy <- do.call(rbind, xy)
table(xy$cut)

 Fair      Good Very Good   Premium     Ideal 
  100       100       100       100       100
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to get more complicated than `dplyr`. `dplyr::sample_n` can operate on a grouped data frame, such that each set of N samples is taken from one of those groups.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  sample_n(size = 100)
#> # A tibble: 500 x 10
#> # Groups:   cut [5]
#>    carat cut   color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>    <dbl> <ord> <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  0.7  Fair  D     SI2      65.6    55  2167  5.59  5.5   3.64
#>  2  1.01 Fair  E     SI1      64.8    58  4480  6.34  6.29  4.09
#>  3  0.7  Fair  G     VS1      65.2    57  2290  5.56  5.52  3.61
#>  4  0.7  Fair  F     I1       65.4    59   992  5.6   5.49  3.63
#>  5  1    Fair  G     SI1      63.1    59  4163  6.32  6.27  3.97
#>  6  2.01 Fair  E     SI2      62.1    66 14948  7.99  7.92  4.94
#>  7  0.7  Fair  G     VS1      56.2    65  2384  5.93  5.88  3.32
#>  8  0.7  Fair  I     VS1      60.2    66  2234  5.77  5.62  3.44
#>  9  0.7  Fair  G     VS2      66.5    57  2575  5.4   5.46  3.61
#> 10  1.13 Fair  F     VS1      64.5    55  7335  6.62  6.56  4.25
#> # … with 490 more rows
```

To verify:

```r
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  sample_n(size = 100) %>%
  count(cut)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#> # Groups:   cut [5]
#>   cut           n
#>   <ord>     <int>
#> 1 Fair        100
#> 2 Good        100
#> 3 Very Good   100
#> 4 Premium     100
#> 5 Ideal       100
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I ended up using your method by creating a data frame (Test.1) that includes the price (edited code on top). Would you happen to know how I would find the mean of just the prices listed in the Test.1 data frame? I cant convert it to numeric cleanly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about not being able to convert it, but you can use `dplyr::summarize` to do whatever summary calculations you need for each group, although that's getting into a different question that should have plenty of answers on SO already.